# объединить std::bitset в один char

Tags: c++

У меня есть 4 переменные которые я перевел в двоичную систему и вывожу в консоль.

```
std::cout <<std::bitset<8>(a) << std::bitset<8>(b) << std::bitset<8>(c) << std::bitset<8>(d);
```

Вывод такой

```
11111111111111111111111100000000
```

как можно объединить эти 4 переменные в один 32х битный char?

Comment: 32 битным char бывает только в теории

Comment: ну почему в теории? есть всякие экзотические платформы, где байт может быть 9 бит, 32 или 36. А ещё была Сетунь

Comment: Речь идет о UTF-32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения значения из битсета используем `to_ullong`, для составления числа из полученных чисел используем [побитовые операции](https://ravesli.com/urok-45-pobitovye-operatory/) сдвиг `<<` и побтовое или `|`

Разумеется если есть изначальные char переменные то можно сразу работать с ними не приьбегая к `to_ullong` битсета.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  unsigned char a = 0x89;
  unsigned char b = 0xAB;
  unsigned char c = 0xCD;
  unsigned char d = 0xEF;

  std::bitset<8> A = std::bitset<8>(a);
  std::bitset<8> B = std::bitset<8>(b);
  std::bitset<8> C = std::bitset<8>(c);
  std::bitset<8> D = std::bitset<8>(d);
 
  std::cout << A << B << C << D << std::endl;
  
  int res32 = int((unsigned char)(A.to_ullong()) << 24 |
              (unsigned char)(B.to_ullong())     << 16 |
              (unsigned char)(C.to_ullong())      << 8 |
              (unsigned char)(D.to_ullong()));
            
  std::cout << res32 << " = " << std::hex << res32;

}
```

> 10001001101010111100110111101111
>
> -1985229329 = 89abcdef

Все зависит от задачи и тот же результат можно получить меньшими усилиями:

```
  unsigned int a = 0x89ABCDEF;
  std::bitset<32> A = std::bitset<32>(a);
  std::cout << A << std::endl;
  int res32 = int(A.to_ullong());
  std::cout << res32 << " = " << std::hex << res32;
```